# How to pass parameter from template to a view django

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

I want to pass a dropdown variable from the template to a function when i click submit button

```
    #models.py :-

    class donnee(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length= 150)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = _('donnee')
            verbose_name_plural = _('donnees filtrage')
            ordering = ['name']


    class Property(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)
        description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = _('property')
            verbose_name_plural = _('properties')
            ordering = ['name']


    class Physic2(models.Model):
        name = models.ForeignKey(Property, verbose_name=_('name'), null=True, blank=True)
        lapropriete = models.ForeignKey(donnee, verbose_name=_('lapropriete'),  blank=True)
        #lapropriete = models.CharField(_('property'), max_length=100)
        description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.lapropriete

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = _('physic2')
            verbose_name_plural = _('physics2')
            ordering = ['name']

    #forms.py:-

    class Physic2Form(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Physic2

    #views.py:-

    def get_materials_one(request, category_slug=None):
        if category_slug is None:
            lafamille= 'general'
            propriete= Physic2Form()
            return render_to_response('material/critere1.html',
                                       {'unefamille': lafamille,
                                        'propriete': propriete},
                                         context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    #template:-

    <form id= "testjson" action="{% url chercher_filtre1 %}" method= "get"  onsubmit = "">

    {{ propriete.lapropriete }}

    <td><input type="submit" style="background-color:#D7D8D4;" value="Search" id= "chercher"/></td>
    </div>

    </form>

    #function:-

    valT1 = request.GET['lapropriete'] 

this don't work
```

when i click on a field in the dropdown list

valT1 = 1 or 2...   it's just the id of the field

i have the fields

Vickers hardness (GPa)
Shear Modulus (GPa)
Young Modulus (GPa)

what to put for request.GET[ ??]

Comment: Where exactly is `valT1 = request.GET['lapropriete']` located? In which file I mean.

Comment: Why in the world you are trying to put something to request.GET manually? If @sandeep answer was not useful, we don't know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you in django 1.3, right?

Comment: @user1788104 - could you answer our questions? Firstly, where does this standalone `function` section belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this and try.

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = Physic2Form(request, data=request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        valT1 = data['lapropriete']
```

Comment: Correct. I was confused where section `function` from his code belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

my function

def search_filter1(request):
    try:

```
    val_min1 = float(request.GET['Vmin1'])
    val_max1 = float(request.GET['Vmax1'])
    T_min1 = float(request.GET['Tmin1'])
    T_max1 = float(request.GET['Tmax1'])
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = Physic2Form(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            valT1 = form['lapropriete']
    print 'val_min1:',val_min1
    print 'val_max1:',val_max1
    print 'Tmin1:', T_min1
    print 'Tmax1:', T_max1
    print 'valT1:',valT1
```

If i select the property 'Shear Modulus (GPa)' when i click on submit button,
 i get this :

val_min1: 44.0
val_max1: 99.0
Tmin1: 44.0
Tmax1: 99.0

```
valT1: <select name="lapropriete" id="id_lapropriete">
<option value="">---------</option>
<option value="2">Elasticity Modulus (GPa)</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">Shear Modulus (GPa)</option>
<option value="1">Vickers Hardness (GPa)</option>
<option value="3">Young Modulus (GPa)</option>
</select>
```

why that ?